# Is there a way to make running code in C++ easily done?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, meson-build

I had some tasks to setup a structure like this:

```
├── meson.build (main)
├── include
│   ├── meson.build (directory)
│   ├── task1
│   │   └── meson.build (header)
│   │   └── task1.h
│   └── task2
│       └── meson.build (header)
│       └── task2.h
└── src
    ├── meson.build (directory)
    ├── task1
    │   └── meson.build (task)
    │   └── task2.cpp
    └── task2
        └── meson.build (task)
        └── task2.cpp
```

Each directory has its own meson.build file with either

```
// meson.build (directory)
subdir('task1')
subdir('task2')
```

or

```
// meson.build (header)
project_header_files += files('task1.h')
```

or

```
// meson.build (task)
task1_sources += files('task1.cpp')
```

The 'main' meson.build file is more extensive, but basically sets up the executables and arguments.

```
// meson.build (main)
project('projectName', 'c', 'cpp',
  version : '0.1',
  license: 'MIT',
  default_options : [
    'warning_level=3',
    'c_std=c17',
    'cpp_std=c++17'
    ]
  )

cpp = meson.get_compiler('cpp')
cc = meson.get_compiler('c')

if cpp.get_id() == 'clang'
  add_project_arguments(cpp.get_supported_arguments(['-Weverything', ' -pthread']), language: 'cpp')
else
  add_project_arguments(cpp.get_supported_arguments([
    '-Wall',
    '-Wextra',
    '-Wshadow',
    '-Wundef',
    '-Werror',
    '-pthread',
    ]), language: 'cpp')
endif

task1_sources = []
task2_sources = []
project_header_files = []

inc = [include_directories('include')]

subdir('include')
subdir('src')

exe_task1 = executable('task1', task1_sources, include_directories: inc)

boost_dep = [
  dependency('threads'),
  cpp.find_library('boost_system', required: true),
  cpp.find_library('boost_filesystem', required: true),
]

exe_task2 = executable('task2', task2_sources, include_directories: inc, dependencies : boost_dep)

clangtidy = find_program('clang-tidy', required: false)
if clangtidy.found()
  run_target(
    'tidy',
    command: [
      clangtidy,
      '-checks=*,clang-analyzer-*',
      '-p', meson.build_root()
      ] + opp1_sources + opp2_sources + project_header_files)
endif

test('basic', exe_task1)
test('basic', exe_task2)
```

When running meson build it simply doesnt find my build files. This i have tried separating and running the files as .exe-files with VSC and terminal, on a linux VM with meson both through the command line and through .sh-files running small scripts. It seems to always be an error.
So, the question is - Is there an 'easy' way to setup a structure to run .cpp files?

Comment: For a simple example project hierarchy like the one you show, the Meson files should be equally simple, and it should be possible to copy-paste them as-is into your question. Also in the project hierarchy please include the locations of the Meson files, and remember to add comments in them to tell us which file is used where. And of course, also please copy-paste the full and complete configuration and build output in your question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Added the locations and the content of the meson-files. You want the entire terminal-output?